# FFMPEG says file does not exist, but, it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG via the streamio-FFMPEG Rails gem – https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

For some reason, when trying to transcode a video file (that does really exist), FFMPEG says the file does not exist.

Here's some output from the Rails console, demonstrating my headache:

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > File.exist?("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/video-app/public/uploads/tmp/20131208-1416-1234-0984/videotest.mp4")
 => true 

1.9.3p125 :002 > FFMPEG::Movie.new("/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/video-app/public/uploads/tmp/20131208-1416-1234-0984/videotest.mp4")
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - ffmpeg -i /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/video-app/public/uploads/tmp/20131208-1416-1234-0984/videotest.mp4
  from /Users/my-comp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:202:in `spawn'
  from /Users/my-comp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:202:in `popen_run'
  from /Users/my-comp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open3.rb:90:in `popen3'
  from /Users/my-comp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@video-app/gems/streamio-ffmpeg-1.0.0/lib/ffmpeg/movie.rb:17:in `initialize'
  from (irb):2:in `new'
  from (irb):2
  from /Users/my-comp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@video-app/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
  from /Users/my-comp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@video-app/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
  from /Users/my-comp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@video-app/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>    '
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3p125 :003 >
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show movie.rb?

Comment: Sure thing, it's part of them gem – and can be viewed here: https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg/blob/master/lib/ffmpeg/movie.rb

Comment: That is really strange because you have already done file.exists? => true. Not sure I'll be able to help but I will vote up

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the fact that the plugin requires ruby 1.9.3 and he's using 1.9.2?

Comment: Nice catch. However, I've switched to 1.9.3 – and the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it cannot find the `ffmpeg` binary itself, not the file you specified. Try to set up the full path for the FFMPEG as well before invoking the constructor:

```
FFMPEG.ffmpeg_binary = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg'
```

Comment: This was the issue – the install apparently did not go as planned. I cleaned things up, installed with homebrew, ensured paths were correct, and everything is working as planned.